# Detect when user scroll to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do something when user scroll page and my special `div` position at the top of the page.How can i detect this?
I use `$(window).scrollTop()` value for this , but this value will change in different browsers and screen widths.

Comment: Before posting a question, please make sure you follow the guidelines

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var $doch = $(document).height();
var $divh = $(".mainrow").innerHeight();
if ($scroll > ($doch-$divh)){
    $Something;
}
else{
    $SomethingElse;
}
```